# Query returns different timezone for future dates only

Tags: mysql

I have a query that should return the timestamp of midnight, based on a datetime. It is working fine, but future dates are off by one hour:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`events`.`StartDate`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS `StartDateRaw`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`events`.`StartDate`, '%H:%i') AS `StartTimeRaw`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(`events`.`StartDate`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) AS `StartDayUnix`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`events`.`StartDate`) AS `StartTimeUnix`,
    `events`.`StartDate` AS `eventsStartDate`
FROM `events`
ORDER BY `events`.`StartDate` ASC;
```

Returns:

[image]

My timezone is BRT (UTC -3), but **future results seem UTC -2**!
Expected: `2014-10-21 03:00:00 UTC => 1413860400`, actual: `1413856800 => 2014-10-21 02:00:00 UTC`

**Past events display fine** within the same query. BTW, the entire system only ever runs and is accessed in UTC-3. It's `2014-10-13 08:53:00 UTC-3` at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that BRT will end daylight saving time on 2014-10-19, "adding" one hour.